# How to implement component lifecycle in react 18

Tags: reactjs

If I have read this [documentation](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) correctly. useEffect lifecycle is independent of the component lifecycle.

If so, How do we implement a component's lifecycle without using a useEffect, or is the lifecycle of a component irrelevant in the new model?

Comment: `How do we implement a component's lifecycle` I'm not sure what you mean by this, can you give some more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: *useEffect lifecycle is independent of the component lifecycle* -  it doesn't say that. It says *try to think about each Effect independently from your component’s lifecycle*

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation. The lifetime of an effect setup via `useEffect` might be shorter than the lifetime of the host component. It depends entirely on how you setup your `useEffect`.

Comment: @NicholasTower, I want to implement the following life cycle for a component (mount, unmount & update). I know how to implement this via useEffect but as I am reading the docs I am not sure if using useEffect for a component's life cycle is recommended. If so, how to implement the lifecycle for a component.

Comment: @Konrad useEffect is independent of the components life cycle but if you have to implement the components life cycle you should use a useEffect?

Comment: Yes, you need a `useEffect` to hook into `mount`, `unmount`, and `update`. It is done by setting up the dependency array, the effect callback, and the cleanup callback.

Comment: It is not independent. I don't see where it's written that it's independent. They only say that you should think in a different way so it makes it easier to work with react